# jhipster : angularjs files and browser cache

Tags: caching, jhipster

I am developping a Jhipster web app.

My problem is that when I update some angularjs files and then deploy the new war file in Tomcat7 the modifications are not taken into account, the clients pc is still reading the old angularjs file.

Is there a way(or a jhipster configuration) to tell the client pc to reload all angularjs file in order to be up to date?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build your app with prod profile  using `mvn -Pprod package` or `gradlew -Pprod bootRepackage` the web assets are minified and **prefixed with a unique code** in `dist` folder. An older version of same file has a different prefix so if it is cached it will not prevent the new one from being loaded.

If you don't see this behavior, it's probably because you didn't set the `spring.profiles.active` property to `prod` in Tomcat and so your app is running in `dev` mode and not using the files from `dist`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried to use prod profile, I am getting this error (which doesn't occur in Dev mode) : Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (run-grunt) on project myProject: Error during : grunt test --no-color: Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (run-grunt) on project bioandbio: Error during : grunt test --no-color. Any idea of what's going wrong here?

Comment: There's not enough detail to help you here, it could be an issue with your nodejs environment, does 'grunt test' (without maven) works?  you should open a new question

Comment: Also with JHipster 3.0 (to be released soon) we are dropping support for grunt in favor of gulp so you may want to re-generate your project with gulp: just comit your files in git, edit your.yo-rc.json file to choose gulp and 'run yo jhipster' remove grunt files. Mak sure you updated jhipster to latest 2.x before doing so 'npm install -g generator-jhipster'.

Comment: ok, thanks. about JHipster 3.0, I am about to start a new project, should I wait for 3.0 to be released?  or does migration from 2.7 to 3.0 will be possible?

Comment: JHipster 3.0 introduces breaking changes, so migration will be hard. We will probably release in March but you can start using it from now especially if you don't use micro services architecture for which documentation is not yet available. Read instructions on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#-generator-development-setup

Answer (score 0):

If your frontend and backend are in the same war: **0.0.1-SNAPSHOT** change this version in pom.xml before making a build to avoid angular caching issues.

If your frontend is split then go to: gulp/utils.js and change this version: '**0.0.5-SNAPSHOT**';